# Excel Formula get numbers from cell using mid and convert to date?

Tags: excel

I have a 12 digit number in column A like so:

```
Column A
041120121601
```

Within this number there is a date 201216 or 20/12/16.

I am trying to get the date from the number using mid:

```
=MID(B8,5,6)
```

I now get this as a result: 201216.

I am trying to format this as a date like this:

```
20/12/2016
```

Here's what i've tried:

```
=TEXT(D8, "00-00-00")
```

This gives me this:

```
20-12-16
```

This is close, but i need it to be 20/12/16

Comment: the date is always in the same position or it is variable?

Answer (score 2):

You can your split `MID` and force a date separator betwixt each number and wrap it in `DATEVALUE`, then just format as a date.

```
=DATEVALUE(MID(B8,5,2)&"/"&MID(B8,7,2)&"/"&MID(B8,9,2))
```

Answer (score 2):

OK, if it starts with a 0, Excel doesn't think this is a number. It thinks it's text. This is important, because one day someone will copy and paste the input data and Excel will automagically convert them to numbers and your formulas all 
will break because the leading 0 is missing now.

So, let's first convert the cell into a number, then back into text with `"000000000000"` format:

```
=Text(Value(A1),"000000000000")
```

Then apply the `DateValue` formula with three `Mid` functions as Tim describes.

(Or your input data are numbers in "000000000000" format, but that's a little unusual.)

Comment: Jobs a good un' `=DATEVALUE(MID(TEXT(VALUE(E2),"000000000000"),5,2)&"/"&MID(TEXT(VALUE(E2),"000000000000"),7,2)&"/"&MID(TEXT(VALUE(E2),"000000000000"),9,2))`

Answer (score 0):

If it's always the same amount of characters then `=MID(TRIM(A1),4,2)& "/" & MID(TRIM(A1),6,2) & "/" & MID(TRIM(A1),8,2)`